# How to listen to multiple Reality Composer notifications simultaneously?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

I have created a notification behaviour for all my separate parts of my 3d model in Reality Composer. I understand that I can listen to a single notification like this:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    let scene = try! Experience.loadScene()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
        
        scene.actions.attackCompleted.onAction = notificationID   // listener
    }
 
    fileprivate func notificationID(_ entity: Entity?) {        
         print(scene.actions.attackCompleted.identifier)
    }
}
```

But what If I have multiple notifications, do I have to create a custom function for each like this?

```
scene.actions.attackCompleted.onAction = notificationID   // listener
scene.actions.attackCompleted1.onAction = notificationID1   // listener1

fileprivate func notificationID(_ entity: Entity?) {        
         print(scene.actions.attackCompleted.identifier)
    }

fileprivate func notificationID1(_ entity: Entity?) {        
         print(scene.actions.attackCompleted1.identifier)
    }
```